# Swagger YAML specification, conditionally mandatory field

Tags: swagger

I want to create YAML schema for REST POST service.

```
 requestBody:
        description: Details of the request
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateCompanyRequest'
components:
  schemas:
    CreateCompanyRequest:
      description: The requested data to the service.
      type: object
      required:
        - address
        - identifier
        - type
```

And how to specify, that the `identifier` field is obligatory only if `type` field value = "BIG" ?

Or maybe the `identifier` field shouldn't be on requried list, instead I should add some comments somewhere to let third party know about the api requirements?

Comment: Is `identifier` included _only_ if `type`="BIG"? Or can it also be optionally present in requests with other `type` values?

Comment: The business spec doesn't precise it, so lets assume it may be included but it it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI 3.0 allows us to define a property as a `discriminator` in the model that represents your superset. You can then create additional models representing your subsets that can change the required flags of your model properties. Example here from Swaggers documentation https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/:

```
Pet:
  type: object
  required:
    - pet_type
  properties:
    pet_type:
      type: string
  discriminator:
    propertyName: pet_type
Dog:     # "Dog" is a value for the pet_type property (the discriminator value)
  allOf: # Combines the main `Pet` schema with `Dog`-specific properties 
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    - type: object
      # all other properties specific to a `Dog`
      required:
        - bark
      properties:
        bark:
          type: boolean
        breed:
          type: string
          enum: [Dingo, Husky, Retriever, Shepherd]
Cat:     # "Cat" is a value for the pet_type property (the discriminator value)
  allOf: # Combines the main `Pet` schema with `Cat`-specific properties 
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    - type: object
      # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
      properties:
        hunts:
          type: boolean
        age:
          type: integer
```